# Call method with parameters through JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, reflection

I am receiving JSON messages from an API (I have full control of the messages sent).
The messages look like this :

```
{
 "function": "function_name",
 "arguments": { "arg1": "Value", "arg2": "Value"}
}
```

I want to use reflection to call the right method with the right parameters and in the **right** order.
The problem with that code is that the JSONObject conversion of the arguments doesn't keep the order of the parameters (which is normal given that JSON is, by definition, unordered).
What I would need is some kind of mapping with the parameters name.

Here is my Java code :

```
    String function_name = (String)json.get("function");

    ArrayList<Class> params = new ArrayList<Class>();
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONObject args = (JSONObject)json.get("arguments");


    if (args != null) {
        Set<String> keysargs = args.keySet();
        for (String key : keysargs) {

            params.add(args.get(key).getClass());
            values.add(args.get(key).toString());
        }
    }

    Method method;
    try {
      if (params.size() == 0) {
          method = this.getApplication().getClass().getMethod(function_name);
      }
      else {
          method = this.getApplication().getClass().getMethod(function_name, params.toArray(new Class[params.size()]));
      }

      try {
        method.invoke(this.getApplication(), values.toArray());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you json array for parameters. You will be able to preserve order as well.
Something like -

```
{
 "function": "function_name",
 "arguments": [{ "arg1": "Value"}, {"arg2": "Value"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON array as Raman suggested to preserve order of arguments.
Since Java doesn't have named parameter passing.
The JSON should look like this

```
{
  "function": {
    "name": "function_name",
    "args": ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
  }
}
```

You can even call more than one function in specific order

```
{
   "functions": [
      "function": {
         "name": "function_name1",
         "args": ["val1", "val2"]
      }
      ... more functions
   ]
}
```

The argument should be the same type and string is recommended because array **should** be the same type in Java. Anyway, if you want JSON to carry argument information , you can do so as the following

```
{
  "function": {
    "name": "function_name",
    "args": [
      { "name": "val1", "type": "int", "value": "1" },
      { "name": "val2", "type": "string", "value": "something" }
    ]
  }
}
```

All data types in JSON should be string as you can create the utility to convert type based on `type`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

So I used raman and hussachai JSON structure, and then extracted the datas like this :

```
    JSONArray args = (JSONArray)json.get("arguments");
    ArrayList<JSONObject> listOfParams = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.size();i++) {
        JSONObject argument_name_value = (JSONObject)args.get(i);
        Set<String> keysargs = argument_name_value.keySet();
        for (String key : keysargs) {
            params.add(argument_name_value.get(key).getClass());
            values.add(argument_name_value.get(key).toString());
        }
    }
```

That worked smoothly. Thanks a lot